# How to assign multi line text to a string in stored procedure in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Following code  on command line

```
select 
   $$
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line '3'
   $$
```

But when I try to use $$ delimited string for setting a variable in stored proc , it does not work
I get error `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "Line"`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testMultiString()
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
    $$
    DECLARE 
       endtime datetime;
       sqlText text; 
    
    BEGIN
      SELECT INTO sqlText  
            $$
       Line 1
       Line 2
       Line '3'
       $$;
      RAISE INFO 'sql  : %', sqlText;
      
    END
    $$;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Redshift, but in Postgres you need to use a different "dollar quote" string when you nest them, e.g.

```
  SELECT INTO sqlText  
        $text$
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line '3'
   $text$;
```

Although a simple assignment would be better

```
sqltext := $text$
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line '3'
   $text$;
```

Or use a different delimiter on the outer level e.g. `$body$`, then you can use `$$` on the inside.

Comment: I just confirmed this works 2022-01-18 in AWS Redshift.